# An elementary question about integers and fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers (i.e., positive integers), and let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$.  Assume further that I have $x \leq y$.

Now, suppose that I have the inequalities
$$2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2}{y + x} \leq z < 2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2 + y}{y + x}.$$

Does this force $z = 2y - x$?

**Update**

There is a newer question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473018), which more or less should have been my actual question.

Comment: Unless I made an error, for x=10, y=100, the lhs is 181.18... and the rhs is 190.09..., so the statement cannot be true.

Comment: @MartinR, can you write out your comment into an actual answer please?  Thanks!

Comment: Please do not edit your question when you realize it is wrong. Instead state why it is wrong and make a new question

Comment: Okay, my apologies.

Comment: There exists a rule that the site should not be used as a "scratchboard" in this way but only to answer specific questions. It is against site rules to keep altering the question in order to make others solve some larger problem.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris: My answer does not apply to your (twice changed) question anymore, therefore I have deleted it.

Comment: Okay thanks @MartinR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed you have changed the problem twice now and we arrive at the third problem of a similar form. In light of this I will now attempt to answer the general case of

$$ a \leq z < b $$

In general, the z is irrelevant. One needs only prove that the RHS is greater than the LHS and then to say that it is specifically greater than the left by a certain amount. This can be done by adding and subtracting on both sides, but a contradiction may be reached (such as z is between two consecutive integers) if multiplication and division are involved, which would imply we entered the rationals or reals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  If $b - a < 2$, does that mean there is only one $z$ satisfying the inequalities?

Comment: Please think before asking, so as not to take up too much of the useful expert opinions on this site. If the range is exclusively 2, there can only be one number in the middle, but inclusively there can be two. You are not in the integers but the rationals.

Comment: Note as I said at the end that multiplying/ dividing on both sides changes the nature of the question. If you multiply by x on both sides, then the 2 is rather irrelevant to the original problem. You have entered the rational numbers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comments.  I know that my $z$ is a natural number.  What I'm asking in this question is whether the given bounds *force* $z = 2y - x$.

Comment: My comments are irrelvant but are a statement about the integers that division is not "proper" under certain circumstances. You have claimed that x + y | 2x^2 by saying that in your formula, because otherwise division cannot be defined in the positive integers. Also, the current formula is incorrect, because it implies z is greater than 0 and z is less than $ \dfrac{y}{y + x} $

Comment: Or rather, that $0 < z - (2y - x) - \frac{2x^2}{y + x} < \frac{y}{y + x}$.

Comment: There exists no integer between these two numbers, therefore the domain cannot be considered as the integer domain.

Comment: So we have $0 < z - (2y - x) - \frac{2x^2}{y + x} < \frac{y}{y + x} < 1$.  My question is:  Does that *force* $z = 2y - x$, if I know that $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$ (without any additional divisibility constraints)?

Comment: Aha!  It *does not* force $z = 2y - x$.  ^_^  $z - (2y - x) > \frac{2x^2}{y + x} > 0$.  Thank you for your time.  =)

Comment: You can make a stronger statement it would appear. Please see the chat

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "no", but I will manipulate it a little to get to that conclusion.

$$2(y-x)+\frac{2x}{(y/x)+1}\leq z < 2y-x +\frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

If we substract $2y-x$ on every side:

$$-x + \frac{2x}{(y/x)+1}\leq z  -2y +x < \frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

Arranging the left side:

$$-x +\frac{2x^2}{y+x} \leq z -2y +x < \frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

$$\frac{2x^2 -xy -x^2}{y+x} \leq z -2y + x < \frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

$$\frac{x^2-xy}{y+x} \leq z - 2y +x < \frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

As $x\leq y$, we have that $x^2-xy\leq 0$, and clearly the right side if positive.

$$\frac{x^2-xy}{y+x} \leq 0$$
$$0<\frac{x^2}{y+x}$$

But there is no way we can see if $z-2y+x$ is less than, greater than or equal to $0$ (which would be the case you are looking for).

Comment: Kindly note my recent update to the original question.

Comment: The left side remains the same. The right side is another positive number. If we do the same as I have done in this answer and in the end we substract $x^2/(y+x)$ on every side, we get $-xy/(y+x)\leq z-2y+x-x^2/(y+x)< 1/(y+x)$. If we multiply by $(y+x)$, we get $-xy\leq z(y+x)-2y^2-yx<1$, but we cannot say if the middle term is negative or equal to zero.

Comment: Hold on, I spotted a glitch in my equations.