# An elementary question about integers and fractions - Part 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus

(This question is an offshoot of the following [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433776).)

Let $\mathbb{N}$ be the set of natural numbers (i.e., positive integers), and let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$.  Assume further that I have $1 \leq x < y$.

Now, suppose that I have the inequalities
$$2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2}{y + x} \leq z < 2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2 + xy}{y + x}.$$

Does this force $z = 2y - x$?

If the given inequalities do not force $z = 2y - x$ in general, what additional assumptions should be made on $x$, $y$, and $z$?

Comment: x=y=even integer.

Comment: @Adelafif, please see the answer that I just posted.  Let me know what you think!  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2}{y + x} \leq z < 2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2 + xy}{y + x}$$

$$LHS = 2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2}{y + x} = \frac{2y^2}{y + x} = 2y - x + \frac{x^2 - xy}{y + x} = 2y - x + \frac{x(x - y)}{y + x}$$

$$RHS = 2(y - x) + \frac{2x^2 + xy}{y + x} = 2y - x + \frac{xy}{y + x}$$

Since $x < y$, $x - y$ is negative, so that we obtain the bounds
$$2y - x - \frac{1}{2} < LHS \leq z < RHS < 2y - x + \frac{1}{2}.$$

Since $z$ is an integer, this forces
$$z = 2y - x.$$